# How to do vector calculation in R

Tags: r

previous code:

```
x<-c(1:10)
```

I want to make new vector y, which +1 to even-number element of x, and -1 to odd-number element of x.

example :

```
x : 1 2 3 4 5
y : 0 3 2 5 4
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ifelse` by creating a logical index with `%%`

```
ifelse(!x%%2, x+1, x-1)
#[1]  0  3  2  5  4  7  6  9  8 11
```

Comment: or `ifelse(x%%2, x-1, x+1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can find odd and even numbers, subset them from `x` and "do maths" on them.

```
x <- c(0, 3, 2, 5, 4)

find.odd <- (x %% 2) == 1
find.even <- (x %% 2) == 0

x[find.odd] <- x[find.odd] - 1
x[find.even] <- x[find.even] + 1
x

[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```